# Problem with two displays on a system running Ubuntu with Preempt_RT patch

Tags: linux, driver, nvidia, multiple-monitors, preempt-rt

For developing a control program i need a rt system. I decided to use Ubuntu with Preempt rt patch. I tried out different kernels (Versions 5.19, 6.0 and 6.2) and patched with the corresponding patch.

I do have two monitors connected to my pc via a nvidia gtx 980 ti. When i start the system with the patched rt kernel, then my second monitors does not get recognized. I made some research and mostly it is recommended to use the nvidia drivers. Unfortunately the drivers do not work with rt patched systems. So i have to use X. Org X server - Nouveau display driver. But that one is not detecting my second monitor.

What i already tried:

- Installing nvidia driver

  - Gives error that rt systems are not supported, aborts the installation
- Plugging the monitor in and out in different states of starting the machine (before system is booted, while system is booting, after system has completly booted)

  - Gets never recognized
- Also tried turning the monitor on and off

  - also never working
- Tried different Kernel versions.

  - Without RT patch nvidia drivers are available and can be used, the second monitor is working. Kernels with RT patch does not work, at least not the kernel 5.19, 6.0 and 6.2.
- Looking into the display settings

  - no second monitor displayed

I also did research on how i can make the second monitor work with X. Org X server but i found nothing. Does anybody has a idea on how to make the system work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by using the 6.1 Kernel and the corresponding patch. I dont know the reason, but the nouveau display driver loaded and also recognized both displays with that kernel.